# Android studio: spaces in javadoc block have different width compared with spaces in block comments

Tags: android-studio, whitespace, indentation, javadoc

Why do my spaces in javadoc in a java file have thinner size?

However, spaces have the same width in doc block and block comment of a kotlin file.

[image: java: doc and block comment]

[image: kotlin: doc and block comment]

Btw, someone always has thinner spaces for both javadoc and block comment, and someone always has wider(normal) spaces for both cases.

Does anyone know where to adjust this setting?

This inconsistency does look uncomfortable.